# Blocking the direct access to images in the upload folder WordPress

Tags: authentication, nginx, curl

To prevent direct access for images in upload folder we have following configuration in Nginx configuration:

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ {
    valid_referers example.com https://example.com;
    if ($invalid_referer) {
        return 403;
    }
    if ($http_cookie !~ "wordpress_logged_in") {
        return 403;    
    }     
}
```

With the above configuration we are not able to access the images directly from browser but with curl able get the image detail using below command

```
curl -i -s -k -X $'GET' \
    -H $'Host: example.com' -H $'Referer: https://example.com/wp-admin/upload.php?item=1' \
    -b $'wordpress_logged_in=a' \
    $'https://example.com/wp-content/upload/2022/10/demo.png'
```

Do we have any other way to restrict direct access of the image through curl request also?